# XSLT C# <XSL:value> based of function returned

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I am trying to retrieve data using XSLT and stuck under this use case. I am trying to pass custPlan, identifier and phone and based on the function conditions it should return dynamic phone number

```html
<xsl:choose>      
<xsl:when test = "starts-with(string(custCity),'Tampa')">   
<xsl:value-of select="local:getPhoneNum($custPlan, $identifier, $phone)" />     
</xsl:when>  
<xsl:when test = "starts-with(string(custCity),'miami')">  
<xsl:value-of select="local:getPhoneNum($custPlan, $identifier, $phone)" />  
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>  
<xsl:value-of select="string($var1_resultof_first/Phone1)"/>    
</xsl:otherwise>      
</xsl:choose>
```

```js
   
  public String getPhoneNum(String custPlan, String identifier, String phone)      
{  
String newNumber = String.Empty;    
if (custPlan == 'X' ||identified == 'Y')  
{
newNumber = '999999999';
}
else  
{  
newNumber = phone;  
}  
return newNumber;    
}  

  </msxsl:script>
```

Nothing is getting returned.

Comment: Please provide minimal but complete samples to allow others to reproduce the problem so we need to see any variable declaration, any XML input that is relevant and of course tell us whether you use XslCompiledTransform with C# or MSXML.

Comment: <msxsl:script language="CSharp" implements-prefix="user">
  <![CDATA[

Comment: It is not returning newNumber field back.

Comment: Is this the right way to call a function?
<xsl:value-of select="local:getPhoneNum($custPlan, $identifier, $phone)" /> 

Declared:
<xsl:param name="custPlan" select="/CustPlan"/>
<xsl:param name="identifier" select="/Identifier"/>
<xsl:param name="phone" select="/Phone"/>

Comment: Consider to edit your question and to provide complete but minimal snippets there, don't expect us to assemble code from comments. I would first test the function with atomic values like numbers or strings before passing in nodes.